# python change superclass init without changing subclass

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a number of servers on multiple devices subclassing from  SimpleXMLRPCServer and all tending to run on port 9999. However, I want to interject the interface on which to listen say

want:

```
server 0.0.0.0  9999
```

or:

```
server host=0.0.0.0 port=9999
```

got:

```
server (*sys.argv[:1])
```

and then the server picks the wrong interface on which to listen because of ordering, or dual-homing because the base-class is 'too smart'.

The base class produces an IP by selecting one from those available on a local host. How can I specify the IP and not break backward compatility for all the subclasses?

typically each server will accept a port, always seems to be 9999. And then hunt through interfacelist to pick one that is no 127.0.0.1.

Suggestion: if an arg is a number assume its a port. If its an IP assume its a host.

```
class Server(SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    def __init__(self, port=1234):
        host = get_ip()
        SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self,addr=(host, port))
```

This feels like a strange compromise, because it reverses the args of the subclasses of SimpleXMLRPCServer:

```
class Server(SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    def __init__(self, port, host=None):
        if host is None:
            host = get_ip()
        SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self,addr=(host, port))
```

if the change affects all the 4 subclasses I would be disappointed, the customers wont know there was a change, but dual homing will now perhaps work with the class being started with an extra argument instead of potluck.

the subclasses all do this:

```
class Server(SimpleXMPLRPCServer):
    def __init__(self, port=1234):
       host = get_ip()
       SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self,(host, port))
```

and the main() invocation is:
    Server(*sys,argv[:1])

Comment: add a new line after `compromise:` for your code to show up properly

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the existing code you're hoping not to change? If it's the first version shown above, that can't possibly work, because (a) you're not sending `self`, and (b) you're sending `host` as the `(host,port)` and `port` as the `requestHandler`. If you haven't actually written the classes yet, then I don't see why you're resistant to changing them.

Comment: Is this question incomplete? You end with "the subclasses all do this:" but there's nothing after it.

Comment: the subclasses all do this:if host is None:
            host = get_ip()
        SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__((host, port))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but let me take a stab at this.

First, [`SimpleXMLRPCServer`'s constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer) takes a `(host, port)` pair as its `addr` parameter. So, your subclasses are going to have to look like this:

```
class Server(SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    def __init__(self, *whatever):
        # host, port = something
        SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self, (host, port))
```

There's no way around that.

If you're just looking to avoid writing the `if host is None` bit on each subclass, just interpose an intermediate class:

```
class BaseServer(SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    def __init__(self, port=1234, host=None):
        if host is None:
            host = get_ip()
        SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self, (host, port))
```

And now, each of your subclasses can be written the way (I think) you want:

```
class FirstServer(BaseServer):
    def __init__(self, port=1234, host=None):
        # any other initialization you need to do
        BaseServer.__init__(self, port, host)

class SecondServer(BaseServer):
    # no extra initialization at all needed for this subclass
```

Of course you *could* do that by monkeypatching `SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__` to change its interface… by why? That's just going to lead to confusion, as anyone reading your code (including you, 6 months from now) is going to have to figure out why `SimpleXMLRPCServer` isn't acting the way the docs say it should be. You get the same benefits out of the intermediate class, without any of the problems.